# Unable to run XMLDiff extension in WAMP

Tags: php, wamp, xmldiff

I attempted to install and run XMLDiff extension, but failed with following message

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_xmldiff.dll' - The specified module could not be found. in Unknown on line 0
```

The file *is* in that said path.

My php.ini file contains correct path to extensions, and the extension itself is linked with

```
extension=php_xmldiff.dll
```

In my php error log, there is the same error message for two more extensions `php_ldap.dll` and `php_intl.dll`